# "web container has not yet been started" on persisting an entity via jax-rs

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs, glassfish-4

### The problem:

I'm trying to implement a simple jax-rs service that would be persisting entities passed as jsons.
A part of the stack I'm using is:

- GlassFish 4.0
- Jersey 2.0
- Hibernate 5.1.0.Final
- Oracle jdbc 12.1.0.2.0

Currently I'm receiving `IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started` on attempt to send **any** meaningful http request to the service:

```java
StandardWrapperValve[com.my.lab.web.BookStoreApplication]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.my.lab.web.BookStoreApplication threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1652)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocatePreparedStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:69)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatementInternal(PhysicalConnection.java:2013)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:1960)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:215)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:586)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:255)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:52)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:992)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.initializePreviousValueHolder(IncrementGenerator.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.generate(IncrementGenerator.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:751)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at com.my.lab.dao.db.AbstractDbDao.saveEntity(AbstractDbDao.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy352.saveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.my.lab.dao.db.__EJB31_Generated__DbBookDao__Intf____Bean__.saveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.my.lab.web.resource.BookResource.saveNewBook(BookResource.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.my.lab.web.setting.swagger.SwaggerFilter.doFilter(SwaggerFilter.java:20)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

### Implementation:

So far I have a resource class, with dao bean injected as EJB (and also you can see some swagger annotations there):

```java
@Path("/book")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Api(value = "book")
public class BookResource {

    @EJB
    private DbBookDao bookDao;


    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @ApiOperation(value = "Post a book", response = Book.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "A book with such id is already exist"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")})
    public Response saveNewBook(Book book) {
        Integer id;
        if (id = book.getId()) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(String.format("A book with id %d is already exist", id),
                    Response.Status.CONFLICT);
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(bookDao.saveEntity(book)).build();
    }

}
```

The resource is registered like this:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/bookstore/api")
public class BookStoreApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public BookStoreApplication() {
        initSwagger();
        packages("com.my.lab","io.swagger.jaxrs.json", "io.swagger.jaxrs.listing");
    }

    private void initSwagger() {
        BeanConfig swaggerConfig = new BeanConfig();
        swaggerConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http", "https"});
        // other BeanConfig methods
    }
}
```

Here is the dao bean class:

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DbBookDao extends AbstractDbDao<Book> {

    @Override
    protected Class<Book> getEntityClass() {
        return Book.class;
    }
}
```

that extends an abstract class, containing entity manager:

```java
public abstract class AbstractDbDao<T extends Entity> implements DAO<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "demo-persistence-unit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected abstract Class<T> getEntityClass();

    @Override
    public T saveEntity(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

The DAO interface is a simple contract with no annotations or whatsoever.
And finally here is the Book json/hibernate entity class:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book implements Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "book_counter")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "book_counter", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
    private Integer bookId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "BOOK_NAME")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "AUTHOR_FK"))
    private Author author;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "BOOK_GENRES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GENRE_ID"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<Genre> genres;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date written;


    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Book() {
        // Default empty constructor for hibernate and JSON data binding
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.bookId = id;
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

implementing Entity interface:

```java
public interface Entity {
    Integer getId();
    void setId(Integer id);
}
```

---

### Configs:

The following are my persistence.xml:

```java
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="demo-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/oracleDB</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.my.lab.business.entity.Book</class>
        <class>com.my.lab.business.entity.Author</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.classloading.use_current_tccl_as_parent" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name='hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and web.xml:

```java
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SwaggerFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.my.lab.web.setting.swagger.SwaggerFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SwaggerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/bookstore/api/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

The application deploys go well, and all db tables needed are successfully created. But on any request a hibernate generated query execution fails at this place:

```java
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1652)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocatePreparedStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:69)
```

In attempt to avoid this I added to persistence.xml

```java
<property name="hibernate.classloading.use_current_tccl_as_parent" value="false" />
```

Which wasn't much of a help.
Also, all my code: resources, entities and dao beans, along with all xml configs are packaged in one war. Besides, this war contains jdbs.jar under *WEB-INF/lib*. I tried to add it to *glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/databases*, which seems doesn't make any difference.

As far as I could get the problem is in the GlassFish classloading process, though I might be wrong. I'm completely stuck here and I'd appreciate any help with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to bypass the issue by downgrading hibernate version to `4.3.11.Final`, and due to that I had to change `hibernate.dialect` to `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`.
Afterwards I faced an issue with persisting new data to old tables, dropping tables fixed it (there were some data-types mismatches, probably caused by dialect differences).